# Looping through animation

Tags: jquery

I cant get this jquery loop to keep going.  I am sure it's something simple that I am missing.

```
$(document).ready(function loop(){
    var div = $("div");
    div.animate({width: '800px', opacity: '0'}, "slow");
    setTimeout(function(){loop()}, 1);
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The second loop of the function will not change anything here.

Comment: I am just practicing jquery, and just want the animation to keep continuing.  I thought the setTimeout would keep repeating the loop function, but I am not sure why it isn't.

Comment: I see one problem with this loop (apart from the fix shown in the answer below), you have nothing that is resetting the div after the animation, so the next time the loop fires, the div has nothing to animate, which could also make it look like the loop is not working

Comment: @Pete Your're right, that's why I asked what OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This would be what your are looking at:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { // anonymous callback function for the ready-handler
   (function loop() { //IIFE construct for the loop function, this will call the function when loaded.
     var div = $("div");
     div.animate({
       width: '800px',
       opacity: '0'
     }, "slow");
     console.log('loop');
     setTimeout(function() {
       loop() //invoke the function recursivly
     }, 100);
   })();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternativly you can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Reference:

[jQuery - `.ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/w664g4ra/)

Comment: its still not looping, but thanks for the reference.

Comment: It is looping, go to the example and open the console. What do you expect to happen? The animation will run the first time but then doesn't have any effect because the css will not be resetted